# Insert new row into Oracle database with C#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, crud

I want to perform CRUD operations via C#. Obviously, I'm very new to this. I managed to delete the record, but I am having difficulty opening a new record. There is procedure for inserting new row in PL/SQL. I tried to write this procedure with C#. I think I'm creating the `attr` parameter incorrectly.

These are codes in PL/SQL for inserting new record. There is no problem here.

```
DECLARE
   a_ VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL; --p0
   b_ VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL; --p1
   c_ VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL; --p2
   d_ VARCHAR2(32000) := 'CONTRACT'||chr(31)||'BISAM'||chr(30)||'REQUISITIONER_CODE'||chr(31)||'IFSAPP'||chr(30)||'ORDER_CODE'||chr(31)||'1'||chr(30); --p3
   e_ VARCHAR2(32000) := 'DO'; --p4

BEGIN


ifsapp.PURCHASE_REQUISITION_API.NEW__( a_ , b_ , c_ , d_ , e_ );


EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
rollback;

raise;

END;

DECLARE
BEGIN

    COMMIT;

END;
```

This the `New__` procedure belongs to `ifsapp.PURCHASE_REQUISITION_API.NEW__` for inserting a new row:

```
PROCEDURE New__ (
   info_       OUT    VARCHAR2,
   objid_      OUT    VARCHAR2,
   objversion_ OUT    VARCHAR2,
   attr_       IN OUT VARCHAR2,
   action_     IN     VARCHAR2 );
```

This is my C# code. And I can not insert a new row. It get errors as shown below:

```
public void InserNewRecord()
{
    SetConnection(); // Sets the connection con = new OracleConnection
    cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "ifsapp.PURCHASE_REQUISITION_API.NEW__";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    string attr_ = "'CONTRACT'||chr(31)||'BISAM'||chr(30)||'REQUISITIONER_CODE'||chr(31)||'IFSAPP'||chr(30)||'ORDER_CODE'||chr(31)||'1'||chr(30);";
    string action_ = "DO";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "info_",
        Value = null,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "objid_",
        Value = null,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "objversion_",
        Value = null,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "attr_",
        Value = attr_,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
    });
    cmd.Parameters.Add("action_", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = action_;

    int x=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

This is the error:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-20111: UserAllowedSite.RECNOTEXIST:
>
> Site not used for user IFSAPP
>
> ORA-06512: at "IFSAPP.ERROR_SYS", line 203
>
> ORA-06512: at "IFSAPP.USER_ALLOWED_SITE_API", line 610
>
> ORA-06512: at "IFSAPP.PURCHASE_REQUISITION_API", line 680
>
> ORA-06512: at "IFSAPP.PURCHASE_REQUISITION_API", line 1117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not expect bind parameters to be evaluated as SQL expressions; they are treated as literal values so when you use:

```c#
string attr_ = "'CONTRACT'||chr(31)||'BISAM'||chr(30)||'REQUISITIONER_CODE'||chr(31)||'IFSAPP'||chr(30)||'ORDER_CODE'||chr(31)||'1'||chr(30);";

cmd.Parameters.Add(
  new OracleParameter()
  {
    ParameterName = "attr_",
    Value = attr_,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
  }
);
```

Then the value passed to the parameter is literally `'CONTRACT'||chr(31)||'BISAM'||chr(30)||'REQUISITIONER_CODE'||chr(31)||'IFSAPP'||chr(30)||'ORDER_CODE'||chr(31)||'1'||chr(30);` and it does **NOT** evaluate `||` as a string concatenation operator nor `CHR(31)` as the 31<sup>st</sup> ASCII character, etc.

Pass the string as:

```c#
string attr_ = "CONTRACT\u001FBISAM\u001EREQUISITIONER_CODE\u001FIFSAPP\u001EORDER_CODE\u001F1\u001E";
```

or:

```c#
string attr_ = "CONTRACT" + ((char) 31) +
               "BISAM" + ((char) 30) +
               "REQUISITIONER_CODE" + ((char) 31) +
               "IFSAPP" + ((char) 30) +
               "ORDER_CODE" + ((char) 31) +
               "1" + ((char) 30);
```

Comment: Many thanx for valuable information. I tried but now there is a different error. It's about the data type.  
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "IFSAPP.PURCHASE_REQUISITION_API", line 718
ORA-06512: at "IFSAPP.PURCHASE_REQUISITION_API", line 1118
ORA-06512: at line 1'

Comment: @Gokhan We cannot help you as we do not have the source code for the `IFSAPP` package. I suggest that you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (since it is a different problem to the current problem) and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE PACKAGE` and `CREATE PACKAGE BODY` statements for the relevant packages (or the relevant procedures within them). We **CANNOT** debug code that we cannot see.

Comment: Thanks so much again. I was getting an error because I set the value of the 'objid_' and 'objversion_' parameters to null. I gave random integer values to those parameters and a new row was created. Thank you for the information you provided for the 'attr_' parameter. It is the important point.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note here

1. ORA-20111.

Generally errors between 20000 and 20999 are user-raised errors, ie, from your own application stack.

2. Error stack

Notice the full error is referring to various packages in your IFSAPP schema. That means you are "successfully" calling the API from your C# app, but within the API, it is rejecting your call.

That *might* mean the parameters are not being passed correctly, or it might mean that the API is doing what it is meant to do, ie, refusing illegal data.

You'll need to add some debugging to see what is coming out at the database side of the call

Comment: Tahnx for answer. I think the problem is caused by the 'attr_' parameter. In C#,  i write the same string as written in PL/SQL.  Do I need to do something different here? Could you comment on this situation?

Comment: I dont know C# very well, but double check the case sensitivity. In Oracle attr_ is the same as ATTR_.  So in C# you might have to pass that parameter as "ATTR_"

Comment: @MTD gave the solution for attr_ parameter. It fixed. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know language you use. However, see if the following helps.

Error you got says

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: '**ORA-20111**:

Error code is in range between -20000 and -20999 which is reserved for us, developers; it doesn't represent a built-in Oracle error code.

Furthermore, it says:

> UserAllowedSite.RECNOTEXIST
>
> Site not used for user IFSAPP

That sounds like "RECord doesNOT EXIST" which - along with "site not used for user IFSAPP" - looks like user IFSAPP wasn't granted required privileges (insert, in your case). That's, though, kind of strange if you managed to *delete* a row; deleting is probably more dangerous operation than inserting, but ... who knows? I certainly don't.

Hopefully, my thoughts will push you at least a little bit into the right direction in further debugging efforts.

Comment: Thanx for answer. Could you comment on the use of the 'attr' parameter in PL/SQL and its use in C#? I think the mistake will be here. I follow the same method when deleting. There is no parameter like "attr_" in the deletion procedure and no problem occurs.